# DD4T: Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.ContentDelivery, Version=6.1.0.348

Tags: dd4t, 2011

After uploading DD4T templates to CM, i have created CT/PT and published a page using these DD4T templates.

The page gets published successfully, verified in Broker DB.

While rendering the page, on a website build using DD4T Visual Studio Template for VS2012, I am getting the error. Following is the stack trace:

[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.ContentDelivery, Version=6.1.0.348, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc895746e5ee6b' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1.TridionPageProvider..ctor() +0
   testDD4TProject.DependencyInjection.DD4TNinjectModule.b__5(IContext context) +32
   Ninject.Activation.Provider`1.Create(IContext context) +36
   Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope) +148
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +266
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +238
   System.Linq.d__b1`1.MoveNext() +296
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +282
   testDD4TProject.DependencyInjection.DD4TNinjectModule.b__6(IContext context) +85
   Ninject.Activation.Provider`1.Create(IContext context) +36
   Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope) +148
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +266
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +238
   System.Linq.d__b1`1.MoveNext() +296
   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +282
   testDD4TProject.DependencyInjection.DD4TNinjectModule.b__8(IContext context) +124
   Ninject.Activation.Provider`1.Create(IContext context) +36
   Ninject.Activation.Context.ResolveInternal(Object scope) +148
   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() +266
   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +238
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +299
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +68

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'testDD4TProject.Controllers.PageController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +247
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +85
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +270
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +80
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +389
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +371

NOTE: The version of Tridion.ContentDelivery.dll in bin folder of this project is "6.0.0.481", however the error/stack trace shows the version as "6.1.0.348".

Is this the issue of version of Tridion.ContentDelivery.dll or something else?

Comment: It seems you are using the `Tridion 2011` version dlls (6.0.0.481) instead of `Tridion 2011 SP1` dlls (6.1.0.348). You should update the dlls with 2011 SP1 dlls and the lib folder(jar files) then you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks Ram G for a quick response.
If Tridion version says : "Hotfix rollup SDL Tridion 2011 - 1",  What does this mean? Is it 2011 SP1?

Comment: No. SP1 will say `Tridion 2011 SP1`. I believe Tridion 2011 is not supported anymore (double check with Tridion support). If you need to use DD4T with Tridion 2011, then you should use 2011 providers `DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011` , not the 2011 SP1 providers `DD4T.Providers.SDLTridion2011sp1` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ram G.

This is resolved by adding corresponding Providers.

However, I encountered a few errors in ninject etc. which have been answered in one of the questions on stackexchange [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470243/ninject-in-asp-net-mvc4/24177953#24177953).